# Clear single toastr message

Tags: angularjs, toastr

I would like to clear/hide a single toastr message among multiple toastr messages displayed at a time. Is there any workaround for that rather than clearing the entire/multiple toastr messages simultaneously. I have tried the following code, but doesn't worked for me.

```
toastr.clear([toast]);
```

Ref:https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr

Comment: You can have close button. Check the configurations.

Comment: I want to implement it programmatically

Answer (score 3):

You can only clear the active `toastr`, **not an already dismissed toastr**.

For example:

```
var openedToast = null;

$scope.openToast = function(){      
  openedToast  = toastr['success']('message 2', 'Title 2');
  toastr['success']('this will be automatically dismissed', 'Another Toast');      
}
//if you click clearToast quickly, it will be cleared. 
$scope.clearToast = function(){
  if(openedToast )
    toastr.clear(openedToast);
   openedToast = null; //you have to clear your local variable where you stored your toast otherwise this will be a memory leak!
}
```

You can check the **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ggr7Ar22wxilpXQP7RGT?p=preview)**

**Note -**
The `toastr.clear()` example shown in the [toastr demo page](http://foxandxss.github.io/angular-toastr/) is not the best practice, as it will cause a memory leak. All toasts are stored in the `openedToasts` array. If you open 10 toasts, the array size will be 10. After a while, the opened toasts will be gone, but the array will never be cleared.

Thus, if you implement your toastr this way, you have to take care your array. If you want to clear an item from the array, make sure that item is active.

**How we can clear the array?**

To clear the array, we can register a destroy event for each toast:

```
  $scope.openedToasts = [];       
  $scope.openToast = function() {
    var toast = toastr['success']('message 1', 'Title 1');
    $scope.openedToasts.push(toast);

    registerDestroy(toast); //we can register destroy to clear the array
  }

  function registerDestroy(toast) {
    toast.scope.$on('$destroy', function(item) {
      $scope.openedToasts = $scope.openedToasts.filter(function(item) {
        return item.toastId !== toast.toastId;
      });
    });
  }
```

In HTML you can check the length :

```
<span>array length: {{openedToasts.length}} </span>
```

Comment: How would we clear the array or remove the array index if there is a close button also present in the toastr?